# Continuously read the last line of log file in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, file, logfile

I have a log file in which new lines are continuously written.

I would like a bash script that continuously reads the last line of this log file, so that I can process the line (e.g. execute a specific command if the line contains the word "error").

I've tried:

```sh
while true
do
    if tail -n1 -f file.log | grep -q ERROR
    then
        echo "$(date) : ERROR detected"
    fi
done
```

But it's spamming:

```
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
sun 21 mar 2021 18:32:41 CET : ERROR detected
```

(a new line is added every minute in this example)

How can I read only the last line and do not have spam for the result ?

Comment: `-f` is used if you want a single copy of `tail` to keep running indefinitely. You don't need to put it inside a larger loop if you're using it that way, because the single copy _doesn't exit_. (Of course, you need to write the rest of your script to _work_ with a long-running program that doesn't exit).

Comment: Also, you'll want to configure any log-rotation tools you're using to signal your script so it can start a whole new copy of `tail` if the logfile gets replaced with a new file having the same name as the original.

Comment: ...that said, it's generally better not to reinvent this wheel in the first place. There are very good tools for feeding logs into analysis tools as they're generated -- old-style (pre-ElasticSearch-acquisition) logstash being one of my personal favorites, but there's not anything remotely like a shortage of options -- tools that have been actively maintained and in heavy production use for years if not decades. Build your own and you need to relearn all the lessons that went into writing the existing options.

Comment: (Also, your current loop can miss lines -- what happens if 20 lines are written as a block, so `tail -n 1` jumps straight from line n to line n+20, so you miss the errors between them?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest with GNU grep:

```
tail -n1 -f file.log | grep --line-buffered ERROR | while read; do echo "$(date) : ERROR detected"; done
```

Comment: Thanks, this is doing exactly what I want!

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly why `tail -f` has been invented:

```
tail -f <logfile>
```

will show the last line of your logfile, so you can follow what gets added.

This can be combined with a `grep`:

```
tail -f <logfile> | grep <text_to_be_searched>
```

In your case:

```
tail -f file.log | grep "ERROR"
```